# jxbrowser-cross-platform dependency fails to install

Tags: maven, jxbrowser

I have followed these [instructions](https://jxbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000012860-installation). I'm able to successfully do `mvn install` if I add a platform specific dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.teamdev.jxbrowser</groupId>
  <artifactId>jxbrowser-linux64</artifactId>
  <version>6.2</version>
</dependency>
```

But if I use dependency :

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.teamdev.jxbrowser</groupId>
  <artifactId>jxbrowser-cross-platform</artifactId>
  <version>6.2</version>
</dependency>
```

On running `mvn install`, it does download jar files for each platform but in the end gives following error:

> Failure to find com.teamdev.jxbrowser:jxbrowser-cross-platform:jar:6.2

Under the `.m2` directory, I do see jar files for individual platforms in their respective folders and there is no jar file under the `jxbrowser-cross-platform` folder.

I was able to find a workaround by adding dependency for each platform individually. Is there anything I'm missing here ?

Comment: This jar does not exist in [Central Repository](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ccom.teamdev.jxbrowser) . That's why

Comment: You have to install it manually with `mvn install:install -file -Dfile =<path to file>...`

Comment: @Hohenheim Trickier actually (I assume the OP already has the correct repo configured), there is no JAR but only a POM dependency so the type and scope is incorrect.

Comment: @Tunaki sorry but don't know this type of a trick but i think i'm not wrong also with my comment ?

Comment: @Hohenheim Yea I had the correct repository configured (forgot to mention), that's how it was able to download the platform specific dependencies.

Comment: @Tunaki Thanks adding type as pom worked for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add a reference to the TeamDev repository for this dependency, since it is not available in Maven Central. From [the instructions](https://jxbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000012860-installation):

> In order to obtain JxBrowser JAR files using Maven you need to add TeamDev's Maven repository to the `repositories` section of your `pom.xml` file:
>
> ```
> <repository>
>     <id>com.teamdev</id>
>     <url>http://maven.teamdev.com/repository/products</url>
> </repository>
> ```

Then, you can add the cross platform dependency, [which is present in that repo](http://maven.teamdev.com/repository/products/com/teamdev/jxbrowser/jxbrowser-cross-platform/6.2/):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.teamdev.jxbrowser</groupId>
    <artifactId>jxbrowser-cross-platform</artifactId>
    <version>6.2</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>import</scope>
</dependency>
```

Note the addition of the `<type>` and `<scope>` that are not present in the instructions, this explains your error. Maven is, by default, looking for a JAR but there is no JAR, only a POM for this dependency, so we [import the dependencies](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Importing_Dependencies).

Comment: Thanks @Tunaki `<type>pom</type>` did the trick for me,correct me if I'm wrong but for my case I had to remove `<scope>import</scope>` as with that it started showing me compilation errors after successful maven build.